# How to structure combinations of dataframes for regression, without corruption/loss?

Tags: python, least-squares, scikit-learn, statsmodels, pandas

I have a data set, redacted sample below. My goal is linear regression. My question is: Have I created unintended results, due to how I structured the df, using concat and/or div?

For example, predicting:
(2nd time rating) minus (base time rating) with
the ratio of (percent #1) over (percent #2 ).

From the df below:
((4 wk nprs rating)-(base nprs rating))
with dependent variable: ((active modalities)/(passive modalities))
I've created dataframes, in hopes of efficiency, and run OLS, all below.

Thank you for your insight.

What I've tried:

```
ctr = pd.read_csv('file_path/CTrial Data.csv') #CTR trial
ctr = ctr.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') #converting all to numeric, except NaN where can't
ctr = ctr.fillna(0)                               #replacing NaN with 0's, dropping results in too much loss
```

> Now the difference in pain perception over some time periods.

```
#OSWESTRY Pain Scale (lower back funcion) 
#THIS scale is 0-50
#using absolute value leads to more than max, eg, 4-(-4)=8, not using abs results in negative values  
ctr['Trial_4wk_diff'] = (ctr['osw_4wk'] - ctr['osw_base']).abs()   #calculating the difference 
ctr['Trial_12wk_diff'] = (ctr['osw_12wk'] - ctr['osw_base']).abs()
ctr['Trial_1yr_diff'] = (ctr['osw_1yr'] - ctr['osw_base']).abs()
```

> Grouping the treating modalities by "active" and "passive" then
> calculating the ratio. These ratings are specifically the perceived
> benefit of each modality.

```
#perceived benefit of active treatment modalities over perceived benefit  of passive modalities
ctr['active'] = pd.concat((ctr['perceived_ben_aerobic_ex'],ctr['perceived_ben_strength_ex'],ctr['perceived_ben_rom_ex']),ignore_index=True)
# 0 NaN
ctr['passive'] = pd.concat((ctr['perceived_ben_meds'],ctr['perceived_ben_rest'], ctr['perceived_ben_surgery'],ctr['perceived_ben_massage'],ctr['perceived_ben_manip'],ctr['perceived_ben_traction'],ctr['perceived_ben_work_restrict']), ignore_index = True)
# 0 NaN
ctr['mods'] = ctr['active'].div(ctr['passive'])  #ratio of active vs passive perceived benefit #Here I simply used .div() 
ctr['mods'] = add_constant(ctr['mods'].fillna(0))
#ctr['mods'].isna().sum()
#4 
ctr['mods'] = ctr['mods'].fillna(0)   #these steps remove the NaN
#ctr['mods'].isna().sum() 
#0
```

> Now running OLS.

```
#OSW 4 week difference with average ratio

from statsmodels.tools.tools import add_constant

X = ctr['mods'] #modality
y = ctr['nprs_4wk'].abs() #pain scale

model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
predictions = model.predict(X)
model.summary()
```

> output

```
OLS Regression Results
Dep. Variable:  nprs_4wk    R-squared:  -0.000
Model:  OLS Adj. R-squared: -0.000
Method: Least Squares   F-statistic:    nan
Date:   Thu, 26 Jan 2023    Prob (F-statistic): nan
Time:   11:14:45    Log-Likelihood: -260.12
No. Observations:   119 AIC:    522.2
Df Residuals:   118 BIC:    525.0
Df Model:   0       
Covariance Type:    nonrobust       
coef    std err t   P>|t|   [0.025  0.975]
active_avg  0.7351  0.059   12.549  0.000   0.619   0.851
Omnibus:    12.434  Durbin-Watson:  2.044
Prob(Omnibus):  0.002   Jarque-Bera (JB):   14.152
Skew:   0.833   Prob(JB):   0.000845
Kurtosis:   2.718   Cond. No.   1.00

>>> fig, ax = plt.subplots()
>>> fig = sm.graphics.plot_fit(model, 0, ax=ax)
>>> ax.set_ylabel("NPRS 4 wk diff")
>>> ax.set_xlabel("ratio of perceived ben active vs passive")
>>> ax.set_title("4 wk pain scale vs perceived ben ratio")
```

[image: graph output above]

> Data below, originally with missing values:

| pb_meds | pb_rest | pb_surgery | pb_massage | pb_manip | pb_traction | pb_aerobic_ex | pb_rom_ex | pb_strength_ex | pb_work_restrict | osw_base | osw_4wk | osw_12wk | osw_1yr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 14 | 7 | 19 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 5 | 35 | 13 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 18 | 19 | 14 | 18 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 1 | 13 | 6 | 8 | 14 |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 3 | 4 | 18 | 16 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 11 | 8 | 8 | 5 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 10 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 15 | 15 | 8 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 15 | 9 | 4 | 6 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 10 | 15 | 9 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 10 | 7 | 2 | 0 |
|  | 4 | 3 |  | 4 | 5 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 10 | 11 | 22 | 17 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 19 | 24 | 16 | 16 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 22 | 16 | 17 | 22 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 16 | 9 | 9 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 19 | 17 | 24 | 27 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 18 | 11 | 16 | 20 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 28 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 23 | 21 | 15 | 14 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 15 | 6 | 1 | 6 |
| 3 | 5 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 24 | 30 | 22 | 13 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 3 |  | 3 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 10 | 0 | 10 | 8 |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 12 | 16 | 14 | 20 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 14 | 13 | 16 | 11 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 22 | 0 | 0 | 22 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 13 | 22 | 15 | 22 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 5 | 15 | 6 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 27 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 15 | 15 | 16 | 14 |
| 3 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 25 | 9 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 33 | 26 | 22 | 19 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 18 | 12 | 10 | 15 |
| 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 17 | 14 | 8 | 18 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 12 | 9 | 12 | 13 |
| 3 | 3 |  | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 10 | 13 | 0 | 13 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 12 | 11 | 8 | 9 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 10 | 11 | 5 | 11 |
| 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 18 | 18 | 13 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 17 | 11 | 10 | 19 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 17 | 16 | 28 | 28 |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 12 | 11 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 18 | 16 | 16 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 1 | 14 | 9 | 9 | 10 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 24 | 0 | 17 | 25 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 32 | 24 | 26 | 20 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 18 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 5 |  | 2 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 19 | 11 | 10 | 5 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 26 | 0 | 11 | 0 |
| 5 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 1 | 15 | 15 | 13 | 11 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 18 | 8 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 15 | 18 | 18 | 0 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 4 |  | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 18 | 0 | 4 | 17 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 10 | 6 | 11 | 7 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 12 | 0 | 15 | 12 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 |  | 5 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 13 | 11 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 14 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 18 | 8 | 10 | 15 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 18 | 15 | 11 | 12 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 12 | 7 | 19 | 14 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 11 | 0 | 20 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 11 | 3 | 11 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 12 | 12 | 9 | 15 |
| 2 | 5 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 1 | 10 | 0 | 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 14 | 0 | 8 | 14 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 21 | 19 | 24 | 25 |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 19 | 18 | 18 | 25 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 22 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 18 | 5 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 12 | 20 | 18 | 10 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 21 | 18 | 23 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 13 | 12 | 0 | 7 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 23 | 24 | 24 | 23 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 13 | 9 | 0 | 18 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 13 | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 18 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 22 | 31 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 23 | 5 | 5 | 10 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 12 | 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 23 | 8 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 12 | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 14 | 11 | 9 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 3 |  | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 16 | 15 | 10 | 9 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 17 | 16 | 23 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 11 | 8 | 3 | 14 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 12 | 5 | 4 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |  | 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 16 | 2 | 4 | 7 |
| 5 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 12 | 11 | 19 | 12 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 30 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 21 | 1 | 9 | 8 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 11 | 13 | 19 | 15 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 16 | 19 | 26 | 30 |
| 4 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 35 | 17 | 4 | 12 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 |  | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 16 | 13 | 10 | 23 |
|  | 4 |  | 5 |  |  | 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 15 | 8 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 16 | 20 | 4 | 15 |
| 3 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 18 | 17 | 18 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 17 | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 25 | 18 | 29 | 22 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 1 | 10 | 8 | 6 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 |  | 4 | 5 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 11 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 10 | 7 | 4 | 15 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 18 | 22 | 19 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 12 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 12 | 11 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 11 | 20 | 14 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 21 | 14 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 14 | 20 | 2 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 11 | 4 | 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 25 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 13 | 16 | 9 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 18 | 8 | 6 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 16 | 11 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 2 | 10 | 5 | 7 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 12 | 9 | 8 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 26 | 17 | 16 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 14 | 16 |  | 0 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |